# Crystal Reports can't import the given Data Source

Tags: crystal-reports

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   dt.Rows.Clear();

   string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString.ToString();

  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
  OrderDelivery Od = new OrderDelivery();
  Od.Activate();
  DataSet ds = Od.GetDeliveryReportDetails();//Here Am Getting DataSource But this Data
```

Source Can't Binding to my Crystal Report :

```
        int j = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;


        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
        info.DatabaseName = "DbName"
        info.UserID = "UserName";
        info.Password = "Password";

        rd.SetDataSource(ds);
        rd.VerifyDatabase();

        rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Abhinavu\Documents\Login\Login\Rpr1.rpt");


        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        rd.Refresh();
```